# UI Testing Assertion as Utility Method doesn't return failure (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Stealing help from this [website](http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/), I've implemented this fix to run a small wait function so I can make sure I wait for elements/pages/etc. to load before continuing testing. The fix works should I use the code directly in the test, but when I put it in a Utility Method in another class it won't return correct pass/fail results.

The problem is when running the following code:

```
func testCreateGame() {
    let app = LauncherUtilityMethods.startApp()
    AllStageUtilityMethods().waitForElement(app.buttons["THISDOESNOTEXIST"])
```

This element doesn't exist, but I'll still see a test pass.
Here is the utility method:

```
    func waitForElement(_ element: XCUIElement, file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let message = "Failed to find \(element) after 5 seconds."
            self.recordFailure(withDescription: message, inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
```

After I insert the direct XCTFail( ) in the if statement, the Test will then fail/pass accordingly. Is there a better way to handle this scenario? It seems redundant to effectively be failing my tests twice, but only one comes through to actually show as a failure.

I suppose I could just add a description on the XCTFail, but that is a less elegant approach as the actual .recordFailure option.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest create that utility method on XCTestCase itself so that it has the context of testcase it is running in. All the assertions need the testcase to either pass or fail. Here is the sample code.

```
extension XCTestCase {

func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement, timeOut: Double  = 5) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    expectation(for: existsPredicate,
                evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectations(timeout: timeOut, handler: nil)
}


func waitForElementToDisappear(element: XCUIElement){
    let doesNotExistPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == false")
    expectation(for: doesNotExistPredicate,
                evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 50) { error in
        sleep(1)
    }
 }   
}
```

and you can invoke as below

```
   testCase.waitForElementToAppear(element: signOutButton)
```

Comment: Works a dream. Thank you! I haven't tested the waitForElementToDisappear code yet, but I did a small combination of your code and mine to get an error message I preferred (on the test itself)

Comment: Glad that helped :)